# Problem with Iphone distribution provision profile

Tags: iphone, distribution, profile, ios-provisioning

I have a problem

There is one iphone software product of our company
and this product can recieve push_notification messages from our push_notification server

this product is going to be on live(namely it is going to be in the APPSTORE)
so recently we are doing some testing work,(the product use developer provision profile,and the server use the development certificate),it works well

but we want to test the product in the REAL Environment
the server should use production certificate ,
the iphone side product should use DISTRIBUTION PROVITION PROFILE

Now the problem is

1.how to install the product in the device using the DISTRIBUTION PROVITION PROFILE
instead of developer provision profile.
2.if I use the  DISTRIBUTION PROVITION PROFILE,can i recieve the push notification message

I am now online waiting for your anwser

thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only install builds that have been built for ad-hoc distribution on your device. Builds for app store distribution will not run on any device, unless approved and installed through the store, as their only purpose is being submitted to the app store.

1: Just build your app using an ad hoc provisioning profile. Delete previous versions of the app on the device. Install the ad hoc build and the ad hoc provisioning profile.

2: I have not tried that, but I think this should work, provided you're using the push enabled app-id for your ad hoc provisioning profile and the ssl key and certificate have been installed on your notification server.